# Calling OnClick of asp.net button with Braintree's onPaymentMethodReceived

Tags: javascript, asp.net, braintree

I am doing a Braintree integration using their custom forms. I have some custom validation on other form fields that I want to run first before submitting the form. As per their [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration) I am using the onPaymentMethodReceived callback so that I can first check if the page is valid before posting back. My form button has a server side onclick handler (lnkBuyNow_Click).

```
<asp:Button ValidationGroup="purchaseval" ID="lnkBuyNow" OnClick="lnkBuyNow_Click" runat="server" Text="Complete order"></asp:Button>
```

The problem I am facing is if I call `$('<%= lnkBuyNow.ClientID %>').click()` Braintree calls the onPaymentMethodReceived function again, which prevents the page from posting back and gets stuck in a loop. The proposed method is to use `$form.submit()`, however if I do that then I lose the onclick handler on the server - which I need. Below is the code I am using to initialize Braintree and then also the callback function

```
braintree.setup('<%= braintreeClientToken %>', 'custom', {id: 'form1', onPaymentMethodReceived: braintreeResponseHandler});

function braintreeResponseHandler(response) {
    var $form = $('#form1');
    Page_ClientValidate();
    if (Page_IsValid) {                    
        var token = response.nonce;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" />').val(token));
        // and submit                      
        //$('#<%= lnkBraintreeDummy.ClientID %>').click();//This would allow the lnkBuyNow_Click of the button to fire on the server
        $form.submit();//This works as expected but now lnkBuyNow_Click does not get fired.
    }                
};
```

Two questions

1. Is there a way to circumvent Braintree's event handler if the page is valid so that I can call `$('<%= lnkBuyNow.ClientID %>').click()`
2. If not, is there a way to trick .NET into thinking that a button was clicked when using `$form.submit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Braintree has a `teardown` [method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/best-practices) which

> will clean up any DOM nodes, event handlers, popups and/or iframes
>   that have been created by the integration

This means I can remove the event handler for the button click and can directly call the click of the button.

What I ended up doing was this:

```
var braintreeCheckout;
function braintreeResponseHandler(response) {
    var $form = $('#form1');
    Page_ClientValidate();
    if (Page_IsValid) {                    
        var token = response.nonce;
        braintreeCheckout.teardown(function () {
            braintreeCheckout = null;
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" />').val(token));                  
            $("#<%= lnkBuyNow.ClientID %>").click();                        
        });

    }                
};

braintree.setup('<%= braintreeClientToken %>', 'custom', {
    id: 'form1', 
    onPaymentMethodReceived: braintreeResponseHandler,
    onReady: function (integration) {
        braintreeCheckout = integration;
    }
});
```